# Rails and iOS Enterprise Distribution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ios, enterprise

I would like to implement iOS Enterprise wireless distribution, integrated with a Rails application.

As Enterprise distribution apps can be installed on any iOS device, Apple (understandably) require that users downloading the app first log in to authenticate themselves.  They then click a link to a manifest file (manifest,plist) that is used to initiate the download from the directory specified in the manifest (which must clearly be accessible, but protected via the same log-in privilege).

I use HTTP BASIC authentication on my Rails app, and I can create a static pages if needed.

My question is, how can I specify a link to the manifest file that goes via the Rails authentication but that isn't accessed via a dynamic route (even the static pages are accessed via a dynamic route).  I believe that if I can find a way to link to the manifest file, that is password protected, then that solution will also work for the app install image.

I can't put these in public, as they need password protection.  I can't put these in the controller / model / view hierarchies, as they all depend on dynamic paths etc.

I'd also rather avoid needing to update a routes.rb file every time I update the App.

Advice on this would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Well you're kind of in a tight spot. If you want a unique fixed path to every version of the image, then there is no other way then just changing the routes file each time. You could also make a YAML file, have the routes.rb load that correctly. So you just need to change the YAML file and restart the application, rather than update the code.

Comment: Thanks. Even if I went with a fixed path, how could I put that behind the authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just re-reading your question, and I think I understand it correctly. When you upload a new manifest file, and new application file, you want the link to be updated, pointing to the new file, while at the same time keeping the old versions online. The main thing here is to keep some sort of versioning id in both the manifest and client file names. Then using that in the URL.

Setup this in your routes file:

```
match '/getclient/:id.plist' => 'clients#show', :as => 'show_client'
match '/getclient/latest' => 'clients#latest', :as => 'lastest_client'
```

The code in the following controller depends on the manifest plist files and app clients being in `app/clients` folder.

Now in your controller, have something like:

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :basic_authentication

  def show
    render :xml => IO.read(File.join(Rails.root, "app/clients/manifest_#{params[:id]}.plist"))
  end

  def latest
    file = plist_files.last
    latest_id = "#{file.split('manifest_')[1].split('.plist')[0]}"
    redirect_to show_client_url(lastest_id)
  end

  private

  def basic_authentication
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
      username == "username" && password == "password"
    end
  end

  def plist_files
    # assuming file format is like: manifest_versionid.plist
    Dir.glob(File.join(Rails.root, "app/clients/*.plist"))
  end
end
```

I am definitely making some assumptions here on how this works. I can't say i've linked a plist file before to download an app. Please comment if you have any questions.